# ggplot2 xlim does not affect ylim

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a faceted plot using `ggplot2` functionality. For the plot I want to exclude all data that lies outside a given interval. I use `xlim` for that and documentation says that "Observations not in this range will be dropped completely and not passed to any other layers." So naturally I expect that y axis will scale to the y value that corresponds to an x value in the `xlim` interval.

```
ggplot (spectrumTable, aes (massIon, intensityIon)) +
xlim (c (targetMass -2, targetMass + 2)) +
geom_segment(aes(xend = massIon), yend = 0) +
facet_wrap( ~ source, scales = "free")
```

The y axis scales to the largest y value in the df which corresponds to an x OUTSIDE the `xlim` limit I have set up (see the figure attached). I do not understand how ``` ggplot2`` even "knows" these y values exist since they should have been removed by ```xlim` and not even passed to the graphics.

Here is the image:

[image: ggplot2 immage]

what should I specify to make sure that only y values corresponding to x values in `xlim` range are used for axis scaling

Comment: subset your data before the plot. `data = subset(spectrumTable, intensityIon < targetMass + 2 & intensityIon > targetMass - 2`. Then you can use `ggplot` with `data`.

Comment: Your code is not a minimal, reproducible example as discribed here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: All it takes to provide a good example that everyone can run is something like this: `p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(mpg,hp)) + geom_point(); p; p + xlim(16,NA)`. I honestly can't recall if this behavior has always been like this or not.